# Elementary Number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The sum of several consecutive positive integers is equal to 1000 . Find all such numbers.

---

I don't know where to start , and how to start in solving this question. So please help.

Comment: Start with basic algebra : if the smallest of $n$ consecutive integers is $a$. then the integers are $a,a+1,...a+n-1$.  Now the sum of these is equal to $1000$. Use the formula for the sum of first $n-1$ natural numbers, to obtain $1000$ as a product of some terms in $a$ and $n$. Now use the various factors of $1000$ to fit pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- From arithmetic sum: $$\frac{n(2a+n-1)}{2}=1000$$
- Think about factorization.

Comment: Thanks for the hint .

Comment: Also, $n, n+2a-1$ have opposite parity